# Send in mail mode?

Tags: email

New to emacs and noticed the built in mail mode.

Once I enter mail mode and fill everything out, what is the keyboard shortcut to send the email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside any major mode you can type `M-x describe-mode` (`C-h m`) to view its description and key bindings.

`mail-mode` reports:

```
C-c C-s  mail-send (send the message)
C-c C-c  mail-send-and-exit (send the message and exit)
```

I recommend you read the Emacs Manual node on [Sending Mail](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sending-Mail.html#Sending-Mail).

Note that [`message-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/message.html) has superseded `mail-mode` as the default `compose-mail` (`C-x m`) mode. See the Emacs Manual node on [Mail-Composition Methods](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mail-Methods.html).

`message-mode` maintains the same keybindings as `mail-mode` for sending mail:

```
C-c C-s  ‘message-send’ (send the message)
C-c C-c  ‘message-send-and-exit’
```